# Testing whether or not a port is already bound

Tags: networking, ssh, port, bind

I'm looking to bind to a port for SSH tunnelling via a simple shell script (likely: BASH), and I'd like a more ... "sane" manner of testing whether or not the port is already bound to another process, and I'd rather not like to grok (read: grep) the output of netstat.

Is there some command or utility that makes doing this sane? I either have terrible google-fu and a terrible vocabulary, or most people don't try to iterate over ports programmatically via a shell, but instead via a programming language.

Comment: A bit less heavy than netstat, though still same concept: fuser <port>/tcp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use lsof:

*-i i   select by IPv[46] address: [46][proto][@host|addr][:svc_list|port_list]*

```
lsof -i 4TCP@0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: You were a few seconds ahead of me :)

Comment: While lsof works, looping through every process and it's open ports is slow.  netstat -tan will give you the list of open ports.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be lsof.  You can do something like:

```
lsof -i tcp:<port> -s tcp:listen
```